# Whether this property android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT is valid or not?

Tags: android, video, video-capture

I use the MediaStore in my application for capturing the video, but it will capture only 8 or 14 seconds ,based on encoder.

Is there any other way to increase the duration and size of video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set duration limit by time in you Intent like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 4); // i.e. 4 secs maximum
```